# Why does my boiler keep firing up?

Tags: heating

My boiler fires up but does it 4 times in a row and then does the same every hour. It's using a lot of money.

Should my boiler be doing this?

My landlord had a heating engineer out and he said it was normal. I've turned the radiators down and the thermostat on the boiler to see if that would help but it hasn't.

I don't know what to do and would like some advice please.

Comment: Do you know the make and model of boiler? Are you in the UK , US, Canada, Oz, NZ, India or elsewhere? - there are differences in heating systems that might affect an answer. Looks kinda like UK? "boiler" not "furnace", "radiator" not "vent/duct/register/..."

Answer (score 1):

Many boiler control systems keep the boiler hot at all times (especially if the boiler is providing domestic hot water as part of its load) and that does have the logical effect that the burner fires on a regular basis, regardless of an actual call for heat, due to "standby losses" (the self-cooling of the hot boiler, requiring more heat to keep it at an elevated temperature so it's "ready to supply hot water as soon as you ask for it."